# Execute query on firestore database but return no result

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I am building an Android application using Jetpack compose library with Firebase. I'm rebuilding the app based on this sample builder Make it so Android.

I want to query a collection on firestore with the name "courses" (Number of documents in it is 1), but when I run the program it doesn't show any documents and it doesn't give me any error.

This is my firestore and rule:

[image]

[image]

And here is my code:

1. CoursesServiceImpl.kt

```
package com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.model.service.imple

class CoursesServiceImpl @Inject
constructor(private val firestore: FirebaseFirestore, private val auth: AccountService
) : CoursesService {

    override val courses: Flow<List<Courses>>
        // I try to query in this
        get() = firestore.collection(COURSES_COLLECTION).dataObjects() 


    override suspend fun getCourses(coursesId: String): Courses? =
        firestore.collection(COURSES_COLLECTION).document(coursesId).get().await().toObject()


    override suspend fun save(courses: Courses): String =
        trace(SAVE_COURSES_TRACE){
            firestore.collection(COURSES_COLLECTION).add(courses).await().id
        }

    override suspend fun update(courses: Courses): Unit =
        trace(UPDATE_COURES_TRACE){
            firestore.collection(COURSES_COLLECTION).document(courses.id).set(courses).await()
        }

    override suspend fun delete(coursesId: String) {
        firestore.collection(COURSES_COLLECTION).document(coursesId).delete().await()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val USER_ID_FIELD = "userId"
        private const val COURSES_COLLECTION = "courses"
        private const val SAVE_COURSES_TRACE = "saveCourses"
        private const val UPDATE_COURES_TRACE = "updateCourses"
    }
}
```

2. CoursesViewModel.kt

```
package com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.screens.list_courses

@HiltViewModel
class CoursesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val coursesService: CoursesService,
    logService: LogService
) : LearningEnglishAppViewModel(logService){

    val courses = coursesService.courses
}
```

3. CoursesScreen.kt

```
package com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.screens.list_courses

@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun CoursesScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: CoursesViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = { /*viewModel.onUpdateClick(openScreen)*/ },
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
                modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "Update")
            }
        }
    ) {
        val courses = viewModel.courses.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(emptyList())

        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()) {
            Text(text = courses.value.size.toString(), color = Color.DarkGray)
            LazyColumn {
                items(courses.value, key = { it.id }) { coursesItem ->
                    CoursesItem(
                        courses = coursesItem
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to query a collection on firestore with the name "courses" (Number of documents in it is 1), but when I run the program it doesn't show any documents and it doesn't give me any error.

Comment: Where is this `dataObjects()` function coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Query takes time to load data from `firestore` as any other apis takes. So we have to do that work in a suspended function to wait for its completion. And due to this as you are not waiting it gives you empty list. You should do these following steps:

**Step 1.** Make the `CoursesService.courses` function suspended using `suspend` keyword in the interface as well and change the return type to `List<Course>` of function to as it is not update it will give complete list ones in this case. You can do it like this:

```
override suspend val courses: List<Courses>
```

**Step 2.** Also make the `courses` variable of type `MutableSnapshotList<Course>` this will recompose the composable to show that updated list like this:

```
val courses = mutableStateListOf<Course>()
```

**Step 3.** Also get the data in `coroutineScope` as the suspended function needs for that you need to create separate function in `viewModel` or use `init` function to call `CoursesService.courses` function and remember to add the new data in the list as the list is `val` like this:

```
init{
    //...
    viewModelScope.launch{
        //...
        courses.addAll(coursesService.courses)
    }
}
```

**Step 4.** Now you have to wait for the query to complete and you can use `.await()` function on the `Result` and then convert it into `list` like this:

```
//...
get() = firestore.collection(COURSES_COLLECTION).get().await().dataObjects()
```

Comment: In step one, when i code this "override suspend val courses: List<Courses>", it was wrong with alert:
 Modifier 'suspend' is not applicable to 'member property without backing field or delegate

Comment: @TranDatK have you also declared `suspend` keyword in the `interface`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the document id is correct.
2. Set FireStore rules to **allow read, write if true;**
3. You can call all documents in a collection like this:

   ```
    db.collection("courses")
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        for (document in result) {

        }
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
    }
   ```

Check for any exception and if not, log your document in success listener.